# how to use 2 collections for different types of data for user of an app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I want to make a collection like `{username : "jack", password : "pass"}`. This represents a doctors login info. I believe I could create that on signup by doing something like this:

```
var Doctor = mongoose.model("doctor", authSchema);
module.exports = Doctor;
```

The above would create a collection called doctor with the filled in data from the form by doing below too.

```
app.post("/signup", function(req, res){

     Doctor.create({username: req.body.username , password : req.body.password}) 
    res.redirect("/login");
})
```

I guess I could have 1 collection for doctors and another for their patients. so I could make a section so that they could edit their profile for their office and another one to add patients to there database. **How would I associate these 2 collections**. considering that they have to sign in using passport local and they could only look at their own patients only. could it be that I could create a link that says view patients and when they click on it I would use passport's `req.user`to find() all the patients. Is that how it's done. I'm learning this by myself and never used 2 collections and I don't know if I'm going down the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You can used you model like this:

```
 var doctor = new Doctor();
 customer.username = req.body.username;
 password = req.body.password;
 doctor.save();
```

or

```
var doctor = new Doctor();
customer.username = req.body.username;
password = req.body.password;
doctor.save(function (err, doctor) {
      if (err) ..
 })
```

Password should not store as plain text you can used bcrypt to create a hash you can find the example how to secure password 
    https://github.com/asimzsaeed/mongodb_node_multi_tenancy_startup/blob/master/server/lib/services/user/model.js

Comment: Hi thanks for showing me how to save to models but I don't think that was the point of the question. The question was about when you have2 collections or models, how can you associate them with each other. for example: one collection is doctors, which you get the data on signup and the other is patients when they add patients. I'm wondering how after  a doctor logins they can view the patient collection for that specific doctor. If you don't associate the right doctor withe the right patient collection other doctors could view other patients. I use passport.